# Aperture 3 - Faces - Is there a way to change a person's name across all photos?

Tags: photos.app, aperture

I have many of photos of someone tagged using the "Faces" feature in aperture 3. They've changed their name since getting married, and I'd like to update my photos in aperture to show their married name.

I can't find any way to do this or anything else online. Every mention of aperture faces renaming refers to changing the name of a single face in one photo. Is doing a bulk change like this possible?

Also, if it's possible to do this in iPhoto, can someone let me know how that works too?

Comment: In iPhoto: Go to the list of faces, click once on any name and you'll be able to edit it. I don't know how it works in aperture though.

Answer (score 1):

As per Frizlab's comment, if you click on a name in the list of faces in aperture (the thumbnails on the corkboard screen), then you can edit the name there, and it applies globally.